# Issue with Nodemailer on Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nodemailer

I get an issue using Nodemailer to send 1500 mails on my server...

Error message :

> Proxy Error
>   The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request POST /option/emailing/send.
>   Reason: Error reading from remote server
>   Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at ********** Port 80

My code :

```
sendEmailing: function(request, response) {
  var mail = request.body.mail,
      transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        host: 'SSL0.OVH.NET',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
          user: '*******',
          pass: '*******'
        }
      }));
  this.userDao.getAllByRight(mail.usersRight).success( function(users) {
    console.log(users.length + ' utilisateurs !!');
    async.map(users, function(user, callback) {
      transporter.sendMail({
        from: mail.from,
        to: user.email,
        subject: mail.subject,
        html: mail.body
      }, function(error, info){
        if(error) return console.log(error);
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
      });
      callback(null, users);
    }, function(err, results){
      console.log(err, results);
      request.flash('success', users.length + ' e-mail(s) envoyé(s)');
      response.redirect('/option/emailing/new');
    });
  });
},
```